# React Typescript Type '[number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>]' is not an array type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I am having a problem with setState in react Typescript, for some reason when i am setting the state VS code highlights the line saying that Type

Type '[number, Dispatch<SetStateAction>]' is not an array type

and
Type '[ILogin, Dispatch<SetStateAction>]' is not an array type.

The first error is there due to me testing to see if my ILogin interface was the problem, but VS code highlights both lines with the same type of error.

This appears to be a linting error as the code compiles and runs without any problems.  Does anyone have an idea as to what could be causing this.

The more i look at this the more it appears to be a VS code issue.  After every npm start the tsconfig.json is changed so that the line "jsx": "react" is changed "jsx": "react-jsx" but if the line is react-jsx then VS code highlights all the imports as errors.  When i have googled this in the past the answer people give is to change it from react-jsx to react.  This makes me feel that the below issue is somehow related as these error highlights do not stop the code from compiling or running.  But my knowledge and experience of Typescript is rather limited so i would not have a clue where to start looking for the problem.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { ILogin } from '../Interfaces/ILogin';
import { doLogin, fetch } from '../Services/Api';


const Login: React.FC = () => {

const [login, setLogin] = useState<ILogin>({
    username: "",
    password: "",
}) 

const [test, setTest] = useState(1);

setTest(2);

const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>        {
    setLogin({
        ... login,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}

const handleClick = () => {
    // Console out the login object for testing
    console.log("Data")
    console.log(login)
    doLogin(login.username,login.password)
    .then(() => { 
        /* Logged in, token saved to cookie */ 
        console.log("something1")
    })
    .catch(error => { 
        /* Error when logging in, probably wrong credentials */ 
        console.log("something2")
    })
}

const testApi = () => {
    fetch('account/test')
    .then(({ response, body }) => { 
        /* Got the data! If token expired, it was renewed and saved. */ 
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
         /* Error getting data, probably not logged in */ 
    })
}


return (
    <div>
        <label>Username</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <br/>
        <label>Password</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Login" onClick={handleClick}/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="API Test" onClick={testApi} />
    </div> 
)
}

export default Login;
```

ILogin.tsx

```
export interface ILogin {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Question updated to show the ILogin interface, i don't believe this is the issue as the same issue occurs for any setState even with a basic type like a number.

Comment: Can you show us your ILogin interface?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Updated the question with the ILogin interface, i can not see the issue been in that as the same error appears even with a basic type like a number, but stranger things have happened at sea, as they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i have been able to deduce this does appear to be a VS Code issue, I have started to use Atom rather than VS Code on this project and I am not experiencing any of these issues.